# Реализация алгоритма на С++ и Ruby

Tags: алгоритм, ruby, c++

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть две реализации построения интерполяционного полинома Ньютона, одна на С++ - которая работает, а другая на Ruby - которая ведёт себя некорректно. Помогите разобраться, в чём принципиальная ошибка реализации на Ruby.

- Ruby http://pastebin.com/DWzBVNbV
- C++ http://pastebin.com/eBfEV5xY

Comment: И каков ожидаемый вывод?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно итерации лишние делает, там в С часть циклов `0..n`, а часть `0..(n-1)`,  например:

```
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
for k in 0..i do
```

Когда должно быть:

```
for k in 0..(i-1) do
```

Там в нескольких местах такое несоответствие.

Comment: Кстати, в Ruby диапазоны `0..(n-1)` можно также записывать, как `0...n` (три точки).

Answer (score 1):

Помимо уже указанных другим ответчиком повсеместных ошибок о границах циклов:

C++:

```
y_val[i] = F(j);
j += 1.0 / (n - 1);
```

Ruby:

```
table[i] = {x: i/n.to_f, y: f(i/n.to_f)}
```

Очевидно, считаются совершенно разные вещи.